# Excessive radiation emission by cell phone when call is connected?

Tags: radiation, bioelectromagnetics, cellular-phone

I have an application called Mobile Guard which one of its features is to vibrate when call is connected and by that allowing you to keep the phone away from your ear until the callee answers. The application states:

"Radiation emission by the phone at the very moment when the call is connected can be as high as 20 times of usual"

Is this true? Is there any evidence/resource for that? I've searched in google and couldn't find anything mentioned about it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about medical science.